# Land Use Public Notification: Invalid geometry

Tags: arcgis-desktop, javascript, arcgis-local-government

I am in the process of incorporating our data into the Public Notification app from ESRI, but when I load in our parcels, I get an error saying "Unable to perform operation: invalid geometry". I have checked the spatial reference, and it is the same as the sample data, and I have tried repairing the geometry, and the problem is still around.

Would I have to transfer my data into the Local Government data model?

Also, I have checked the Chrome DevTools, and all it tells me is "Error: Failed to execute query".

Comment: Well, it looks like it was my fault. I migrated my data into a LGIM schema, and everything is running properly.